# MapInfo layout templates for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, printing

I have a series of MapInfo layouts that I use as templates for various standard map sizes (eg A0, A4 etc) that contain title blocks, and I wondered what is the best method for getting these into QGIS, if possible.

If not, can someone suggest how to create standard frames and title blocks?

Comment: Is that possible to import ArcMap's title block to QGIS?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128349)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128349)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can make use of the Print composer in order to create a print layout i.e. A0 or A4.

1. Open QGIS
2. Choose `File ‣ New Print Composer`
3. Create your desired layout
4. Choose `Save as template` [image: Print composer, save as template button]
5. Done!

You can re-use this template anytime you want.